# How to read nested objects from object in Thymeleaf to map it with POJO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have created a simple application with Spring boot and Thymeleaf, it reads data from mongo db and renders it on the HTML form which can be edited and submitted back to the server to save in db.
The problem is that the POJO contains nested objects which when reading from the server is fine but when sending it back creates the problem as it is not able to map the nested object properly.

The problem is nested object is part of the attribute which means it does not needs to added by addAttribute at controller, because as shown in following code I can easily access nested objects at the view level.
But when sending the object back to controller it is not able to map nested object properly to the Object.

*Controller class*

```
public class ProfileController extends Controller {

//    @Autowired
    private final ProfileService profileService;

    @GetMapping("/getprofile/{username}")
    public String getProfile(@PathVariable String username, Model model){
        Profile profile = profileService.getProfile(username);
        model.addAttribute("profile",profile);
        return "user.html";
    }

    @PostMapping(path="/updateprofile/{username}", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE })
    public String updateProfile(@PathVariable String username, @RequestBody Profile profile) {
        Profile updatedProfile = profileService.updateProfile(profile, username);
//        System.out.println("Testing  "+profile);
            return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

*POJO class*
Following code shows the model class for the Object which we send to view layer and back to the controller

```
@Data
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private String id;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String username;

    private String profileImage;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String role;
    private String quote;

    private Social socialLinks;

    private About about;
    private List<Project> projects;

    public Profile(String username,
                   String profileImage,
                   String firstName,
                   String middleName,
                   String lastName,
                   String role,
                   String quote,
                   Social socialLinks,
                   About about,
                   List<Project> projects) {
        this.username = username;
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.role = role;
        this.quote = quote;
        this.socialLinks = socialLinks;
        this.about = about;
        this.projects = projects;
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Social {
    private String linkedin;
    private String github;
    private String twitter;
    private String discord;
    private String stackoverflow;
    private String instagram;
    private String facebook;
}
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class About {

    private String intro;
    private List<String> skills;
    private String aboutImage;
    private String cv;
}
```

Since html forms sends data as url enconded format, a converter config logic is created to parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded format send by HTML forms to map it with the model class. This converter class is registered using WebMVCConfigurer interface

*Converter class*

```
public class ProfileConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Profile> {

    private static FormHttpMessageConverter converter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return (Profile.class == clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected Profile readInternal(Class<? extends Profile> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        Map<String, String> vals = converter.read(null, inputMessage).toSingleValueMap();

        return mapper.convertValue(vals, Profile.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Profile profile, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {

    }
}
```

*HTML form*
In the following HTML, clearly we can see that accessing nested object is not an issue and on clicking submit button it is able send the form data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded format to the controller

```
<form th:action="@{/v1/updateprofile/{username}(username=${profile.username})}" th:object="${profile}" th:method="post">
                            <label>Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{username}">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{firstName}">
                            <label>Middle Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{middleName}">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{lastName}">
                            <label>Role</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{role}">
                        <label>Quote</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{quote}">
                    <label>Social Links</label>
                                <label>LinkedIn</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{socialLinks.linkedin}">
                                <label>Github</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{socialLinks.github}">
                                <label>Twitter</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{socialLinks.twitter}">
                                <label>Discord</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{socialLinks.discord}">
                                <label>Stackoverflow</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{socialLinks.stackoverflow}">
                                <label>Instagram</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{socialLinks.instagram}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3">Save Project</button>
            </form>
```

Error I am getting on sending the form data to the server.
From this I can understand the problem is with mapping the nested object which spring boot is not able identify within the model class, rest all other fields are being recognised by it, as shown in the following error log.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Unrecognized field "socialLinks.linkedin" (class dev.jcodex.api.portfolio.model.Profile), not marked as ignorable (10 known properties: "middleName", "lastName", "profileImage", "username", "projects", "firstName", "quote", "about", "role", "socialLinks"]) at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: dev.jcodex.api.portfolio.model.Profile["socialLinks.linkedin"])
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "socialLinks.linkedin" (class dev.jcodex.api.portfolio.model.Profile), not marked as ignorable (10 known properties: "middleName", "lastName", "profileImage", "username", "projects", "firstName", "quote", "about", "role", "socialLinks"])
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: dev.jcodex.api.portfolio.model.Profile["socialLinks.linkedin"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4544)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:4475)
    at dev.jcodex.api.portfolio.service.ProfileConverter.readInternal(ProfileConverter.java:29)
    at dev.jcodex.api.portfolio.service.ProfileConverter.readInternal(ProfileConverter.java:15)
```